# I am unable to access a WP admin area

Tags: wordpress, redirect, wp-admin

When i enter www.example.com/wp-admin/ it redirect me another page of site. I tried every possible way including deactivate all plugin and theme but still got redirecting issue. Please help me . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of using, www.example.com/wp-admin/ use  `www.example.com/wp-login.php/`

Comment: No i'm using server (hostgator)